# Display custom taxonomy attached to the post on post single page

Tags: categories, custom-taxonomy, taxonomy, terms

I need to display the first custom taxonomy attached to the post on post single page. The custom taxonomy is similar to category attached to the posts. I need to display the first custom taxonomy with link to be displayed.

My initial thoughts is to use get_categories but theres now way to define a specific taxonomy?

I get something similar for category by passing this kind of query:

```
<?php $category = get_the_category();
if ($category) {
    echo '<a href="' . get_category_link( $category[0]->term_id ) . '" title="' . sprintf( __( "View all posts in %s" ), $category[0]->name ) . '" ' . '>' . $category[0]->name.'</a> ';
}
?>
```

But something similar for custom taxonomy is not working.

Any help is much appreicated, Thanks

Answer (score 3):

You can get every Taxonomy by

```
$categories = get_the_terms( get_the_id(), $taxonomy-slug );

if ( is_array( $categories ) ) {

    foreach ( $categories as $category ) {
        echo '<a href="' . get_term_link( $category->term_id ) . '" title="' . sprintf( __( "View all posts in %s" ), $category->name ) . '" ' . '>' . $category->name.'</a> ';
    }

}
```

Just fill in the slug of your custom taxanomy, and you are good to go.

If you just want to output the first Name, make a `break` after the `echo`.

`get_the_terms()` returns an Array of Taxonomyobjects, and you can easily output the first one.

Comment: Didn't get an idea, can you elaborate with some more detail? thanks

Comment: There you go, @Krunal :-)

Comment: Hi, tried but this doesn't worked..

Comment: can you post your code?

Comment: Just the code you provided, and passing only the taxonomy-slug of my custom taxonomy

Comment: what does `print_r($categories)` deliver?

Comment: This print this... Array ( [25] => stdClass Object ( [term_id] => 25 [name] => Humility [slug] => humility [term_group] => 0 [term_taxonomy_id] => 25 [taxonomy] => wellness_topics [description] => [parent] => 18 [count] => 3 [object_id] => 57 ) )


However, with previous code I get Catchable fatal error: Object of class WP_Error could not be converted to string in

Comment: one more edit..

Comment: I'm passing custom taxonomy slug as, $taxonomy-slug = 'topics'; above your code, however still I receive the same error...  Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '=' in C:\wamp\www\wpproject\wp-content\themes\themename\templates\content-single.php on line 13

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/6865/discussion-between-fischi-and-krunal)

Comment: hi, sorry I was in a meeting.. we have this at line no. 13 ... echo '<a href="' . get_term_link( $category->term_id ) . '" title="' . sprintf( __( "View all posts in %s" ), $category->name ) . '" ' . '>' . $category->name.'</a> ';

Comment: Please use the chat for this.